# wordpress "leave a comment"

Tags: wordpress, function, comments

I'm a bit lost...
I am building a theme from scratch in WordPress, and I'm using a plugin which includes "leave a comment", but when I click in the link, it does nothing (well, it just goes to the full post instead of the excerpt), but there is not any space where you can actually leave a comment. I suppose, because I am building the theme from scratch, I should include a function for it in functions.php but.... I don't know how to start and less make the relation with the "leave a comment" from the plugin.

So, that is the part where the plugin includes the sentence:

case 'comment':
                        if ( !post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) ) :
                            // Get comment wrapper class
                            $comment_class   = apply_filters( PT_CV_PREFIX_ . 'field_meta_class', 'comments-link', 'comment' );
                            $prefix_text     = apply_filters( PT_CV_PREFIX_ . 'field_meta_prefix_text', '', 'comment' );

```
                        ob_start();
                        comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', PT_CV_DOMAIN ), __( '1 Comment', PT_CV_DOMAIN ), __( '% Comments', PT_CV_DOMAIN ) );
                        $comment_content     = ob_get_clean();
                        $html[ 'comment' ]   = sprintf( '<span class="%s">%s %s</span>', esc_attr( $comment_class ), balanceTags( $prefix_text ), $comment_content );
                    endif;
                    break;
```

Then.... should I create a function in functions.php called comments_popup_link?????

Any help or any clarification for my head will be very helpful.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What comment plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm using one called Content views (content-views-query-and-display-post-page), does it matters? I mean.... it is not only the text of "leave a comment" what is this plugin displaying? So... how do I create the box for the comments?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is very silly, but just adding  in my single.php because I want it only in single post.

So definitely the plugin only writes the sentence "leave a comment" next to the meta information about author, date and category.